# can I use hostname from ssh config in git clone?

Tags: git, ssh, permissions, sudo

Per git [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#_git_urls) the following syntax is supported for `git clone <directory>` command:

```
The following syntaxes may be used
ssh://[user@]host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/
An alternative scp-like syntax may also be used with the ssh protocol:
[user@]host.xz:path/to/repo.git/
```

and I have in the ssh config file the following:

```
Host *
    PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa
    HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa
Host aws
  User ubuntu
  HostName ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
  IdentityFile /Users/xxxxxxxx/.ssh/aws.pem
  Port 22
```

Here is the result of each git command I tried:

1. first syntax with username, full hostname and no port

   ```
   sudo git clone ssh://ubuntu@ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/var/www/.git
   ```

   result: success
2. first syntax full name, hostname from config file and no port

   ```
   sudo git clone ssh://ubuntu@aws/var/www/.git
   ```

   result: `Could not resolve hostname aws: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`
3. first syntax with full hostname, no username and no port

   ```
   sudo git clone ssh://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/var/www/.git
   ```

   result:`fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Plea`
4. first syntax with username, IP and no port

   ```
   sudo git clone ssh://ubuntu@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/var/www/.git
   ```

   result:success
5. first syntax with IP, no username and no port

   ```
   sudo git clone ssh://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/var/www/.git
   ```

   result:same error as #3
6. first syntax with username, a domain name that takes to my server and no port

   ```
   sudo git clone ssh://ubuntu@example.com/var/www/.git
   ```

   result:success

- I'm concluding the username is always needed so I would like to know why the syntax in the git docs indicates it is optional. is there something wrong am doing ?
- why no password or private key was ever asked ?
- ssh config file has no indication of IP, or other hostnames used but they still work, why ?
- why the hostname aws doesn't work ?
- does this all mean my remote repository is accessible by anyone without the need for authentication ??
  I tried adding the flag --verbose for all above commands but it doesn't do anything. is there a way to find out what happened behind the scene for git clone or a log file to check ?

What I tried is above in the question, and am expecting the obvious result of the syntax to work as indicated in the doc but it did  not.

Comment: A lot of questions :(

Comment: Why `sudo` ? If the `.ssh/config` you showed us is for user `xxxxxxx` (as in `/Users/xxxxxxxx/.ssh/aws.pem`), when running `sudo`, ssh commands will be run as root (<- a different user) and will _not_ use that ssh config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can I use hostname from ssh config in git clone?

Not only you can — it's the recommended way.

> `sudo git clone ssh://ubuntu@aws/var/www/.git`

Here is the main problem — you use `sudo` and it runs `git clone` under a different user `root`  so `ssh` (running from `git`) doesn't get access to your `~/.ssh/config`. **Do not use `sudo` with `git`**, it's almost never required and very often leads to problem like this.

> why no password or private key was ever asked ?

Because `ssh` running under `root` cannot resolve the name and cannot connect. No need to authenticate.

PS. Additional advice: put the section under `Host *` in your `~/.ssh/config` at the end of the file; `ssh` reads config in different order — first executed command wins. So first put the most specific commands, put `Host *` last.

Comment: git wont be able to clone without sudo because of permissions so what's the solution if the permissions cant be changed ?

Comment: @AmineTbaik The solution is to use `sudo` to fix permissions and them use `git` without `sudo`.

Comment: @AmineTbaik You can use `sudo git` but you need to configure SSH and keys for the **root** user, not the current user. And then you need to use `sudo` for every access and operation in the directory. Which is hardly less tedious.